# Magento 2: Custom Setup Wizard to be Implemented in Custom Module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, forms, web-setup-wizard

I would like to implement setup the custom steps Wizard in Magento custom module on the Magento admin.

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/pattern-library/navigation/wizard/wizard.html#1-basic-process-ie-deploy-tool

Wizard should have 4-5 steps. **i.e. Step-1 ...Step-5**

Does anyone have any ideas which module should I take as a reference in terms of UI and some HTML UI code?

Any related modules available at least JS component?

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? Trying something similar.

Comment: @simon not yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the Configurable Product configurations wizard (but it's all AJAX and secret html rendering, it's not fun) but that is what you could base it off.
On a configurable Product Under the Configurations Fieldset, click the Edit Configurations button and a modal opens which then loads the Wizard.

Good Luck